# Order div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a few divs with some data  :

```
<div id="div_1">data1</div>
<div id="div_2">data2</div>
<div id="div_3">data3</div>
```

I would like to allow the user ordering them the way he likes. 
What would be the best solution to do so ? I was thinking about adding two arrows buttons to every div with the possibility to move them up or down.

Comment: You can  use Jquery Sortable plugin for this. http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery UI has a sortable component that might fit your needs : http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$("i").each(function(i, el) {
   el.title = "click";
   var div = $("div");
   $(el).on("click", function(e) {
     var elem = $(this).parent();
     if ($(this).index() === 0) {
       elem.next().is(div)
       ? elem.insertAfter(elem.next())
       : elem.insertBefore("div:first")
     } else {
       elem.prev().is(div)
       ? elem.insertBefore(elem.prev())
       : elem.insertAfter("div:last")
     }
   })
});
```

```css
div {
  font-size:32px;
}
i {
  display:inline-block;
  font-style:normal;
  opacity:0.25;
  font
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="div_1"><i>⬇</i>data1<i>⬆</i></div>
<div id="div_2"><i>⬇</i>data2<i>⬆</i></div>
<div id="div_3"><i>⬇</i>data3<i>⬆</i></div>
```